Pass Map of parameters to constructor as equivalent to passing these parameters "manually"?
Can I pass a Map of parameters to a constructor/function instead of typing them all manually?
A use case is when creating a complex widget (MyComplexWidget) containing a few basic widgets (case in point a date picker with a textfield and an icon, say).
Another use case is when building the parameters slowly into a Map depending on different program logic.
Adding functionality to the complex widget to accept optional parameters for each and every containing widget is painfully awkward and will definitely include changing names because of parameters with same name (e.g. width).
I would like know if I can pass optional parameters to each of the basic widgets via the constructor of MyComplexWidget like:
MyComplexWidget(paramsA:<String,dynamic>{width:100, ...}, paramsB:<String,dynamic>{height:200, ...});

where,
class MyComplexWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String,dynamic>? paramsA;
  final Map<String,dynamic>? paramsB;
  const MyComplexWidget({super.key, this.paramsA, this.paramsB});

  @override
  build(BuildContext context){
    return Column(children:[
      WidgetA(paramsA ?? <String,dynamic>{width:100, onTap:(){...}, ...}),
      WidgetB(paramsB ?? <String,dynamic>{height:100, onTap:(){...}, ...})
    ]
  }
}

Alas, do WidgetA and WidgetB (basic widgets) understand that they have to "expand" the input map? Perhaps if there was a factory method in Widget which takes in a map and "expands" it. But this will blow null-safety.
Otherwise what is the usual practice when allowing to pass (optional) parameters via the complex widget to each of its contained items?

well, you need to pass them by hand, here is one of the "best" example of passing params from one widget to another: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/main/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L637

There is no way to do what you want since it's not type-safe and since it would require runtime reflection.

Thank you @pskink @jamesdlin. I was thinking I could do something with ClassMirror, DeclarationMirror, ParameterMirror but importing the dart::mirrors package is like a miasma. It fails even for a cli exe.

@pskink I did not understand your reference unless it is what I think it is: TINA but exhaustively adding parameters from one widget to another (like unloading/loading two lorries back-to-back by-hand). Sorry for my newbieness.

yes, it is like unloading/loading two lorries back-to-back by-hand :-(
